# Find out the source component of a missing Suspense error

Tags: reactjs, debugging, react-suspense

When not providing a required [React Suspense](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html) with a fallback and getting an error like `A React component suspended while rendering, but no fallback UI was specified`, is there a way to find out the source of the error (I guess internally a promise is thrown)? The stack trace is quite unspecific and gives not really a hint which component suspended.

Comment: seriously, no answers here? yikes!